# MediaPlayer played sound twice in onCreate method

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

MediaPlayer played sound twice in onCreate method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.v1);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
```

When onCreate method stard the sound played twice. How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe is the several instance of activity in your code?

Comment: @IllyaBublyk, that all code what n onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to start sound onCreate :

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.v1);
        mPlayer.start();
    }
```

Then stop it on destroy:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mPlayer.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: oO That worked, but without onDestroy sound called twice. Why?

Comment: Answering this not that easy .. it depends on what activity goes through .. for example: rotating device, opening Keyboard can lead to recreate activity. Generally system will recreate activity when device configuration changes .. if you provide your code .. we can help better.